# Only show focused toolbar for Gutenberg Block with Multiple text fields

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to create a block with multiple text fields. That's easy enough, but when I select the block to edit it, both of the toolbars show. I've searched the documentation and can't find anything.

Here's the JSX code that mostly works. It add a heading, paragraph, and image to the block. But when one RichText element is in focus, both toolbars show, and that's annoying.

```
const { registerBlockType, RichText, AlignmentToolbar, BlockControls, InspectorControls, MediaUpload } = wp.blocks;
const { Button, TextControl } = wp.components;

registerBlockType( 'skulogic/header', {
    title: 'SKULogic Header',
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    category: 'layout',

    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'h2',
        },
        content: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'p',
        },
        mediaID: {
            type: 'number',
        },
        mediaURL: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            selector: 'div',
            attribute: 'data-src',
        },
    },

    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        const { mediaID, mediaURL, title, content } = attributes;

        const onChangeTitle = value => {
            setAttributes( { title: value } );
        };

        const onSelectImage = media => {
            setAttributes( {
                mediaURL: media.url,
                mediaID: media.id,
            } );
        };

        const onChangeContent = newContent => {
            setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
        };

        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <RichText
                    tagName="h2"
                    placeholder={ 'Page Header' }
                    value={ title }
                    onChange={ onChangeTitle }
                />
                <RichText
                    tagName="p"
                    placeholder={ 'Page Content' }
                    value={ content }
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                />
                <MediaUpload
                    onSelect={ onSelectImage }
                    type="image"
                    value={ mediaID }
                    render={ ( { open } ) => (
                        <Button className={ mediaID ? 'image-button' : 'button button-large' } onClick={ open }>
                            { ! mediaID ? 'Upload Image' : <img src={ mediaURL } /> }
                        </Button>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save( { attributes, className } ) {
        const { mediaID, mediaURL, title, content } = attributes;

        const divStyle = {};
        if( mediaURL ) {
            divStyle.backgroundImage = 'URL('+mediaURL+')';
        }

        return (
            <div className={ className } data-src={ mediaURL } style={ divStyle }>
            <h2>{ title }</h2>
            <p>{ content }</p>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

See attached screenshot showing the toolbar for both the `<h2>` and `<p>` elements. I want to only show the one that is in focus.

[image: Two toolbars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<RichText>` has a property, `isSelected`. When `isSelected` is true, the controls show. By default `isSelected` is representative of the current block being selected.

from [the docs](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/f95b2d5b952e7a495128d6cb5ca90cc42cf4e169/editor/components/rich-text/README.md)

> isSelected: Boolean
>
> Optional. Whether to show the input is selected or not in order to show the formatting controls. By default it renders the controls when the block is selected

`isSelected` is also a prop (I think?) that can be passed into `edit({ isSelected })`. `isSelected` by default works off of the current block being selected.

So the default is `<RichText .. isSelected={ isSelected }>`.

I used to have a solution for this, back in 2.2 when `focus` was used, but things have changed. Regardless, you can probably overwrite this by writing your own JS to see if the current `<RichText>` component is focus'ed or not. & That'll toggle your toolbars.

---

UPDATE:

From one of the Gutenberg developers directly:

> **@youknowriad**
>
> in the current version you can use state and `onFocus` on RichText to keep track of the currently focused RichText, but in the next version, it should be done automatically

---

UPDATE 2:

Someone experienced your exact issue, shows code provided solution: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6740#issuecomment-388829359